# Have the Bold and Italic shortcuts intentionally removed?

Tags: bug

Traditionally one's be able to use `*word*` to italicize the word, or `_word_`.

And normally using `**word**` would bold the word.

These don't seem to be working. **This should be bold.** *This should be italic.*

The MCE buttons on the input don't work either (they merely add the same, non-working, shortcuts).

## Heading

### Heading

Should the headings be bold as well? I can't remember. They work for size.

[Main site test (Deleted answer)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/104537/3270)

Lists and the shortcut for them seem to still function.

### SOLUTION ------------

This site uses OpenSans from Google Webfonts. If you *also* have OpenSans installed on your system locally, there may be a conflict. Disabling your local version and relaunching the browser *might* allow the various faces to once again appear to you.

Comment: If this should not be a duplicate, please [edit] and ping me. Meta reviews are not exactly reliable.

Comment: Actually.. it may be.... Seems Safari shows them. So it actually *might* be a duplicate. Google webfont used on site while same google font installed locally... doesn't work in the google browser.. interesting.

Comment: Ha! Turned off the locally installed version of OpenSans, relaunched Chrome.... and now they show. It would seem there's some odd conflict with the Webfont if the local version is installed.

Comment: I had the same thing a couple months back, is there a way to make it *not* happen?

Comment: @WELZ Just disable OpenSans on your system.. not ideal... But here.. Chrome has the issue, Safari doesn't. I updated Chrome yesterday. So I think it *may be* a browser bug more than anything. Prior to the update yesterday Chrome was fine.

Comment: Oh.. and I suspect that the order of load matters. OpenSans active locally then launch browser = issue. Launch browser, then activate OpenSans locally = no problem.

Comment: It's weird I have no problem with bold on this version of the site. But I have problems with bold on all the other stack exchange sites.